# как вывести сумму одним числом?

Tags: php

Дан массив с числами. Найдите сумму элементов, расположенных от начала массива до первого отрицательного числа.

```
//мое решение

<?php 
$arr = [2, 5, 4, -1, 0, 7 ,9];
$sum =0;

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if($val <= 0) {
            break;
    }else{
         echo $sum = $sum + $val;
    }
}
?>
```

\как вывести суму одним числом? Вывести 11.

Comment: ну что сложного-то???? посчитать сначала в переменную, потом вывести эту переменную.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = [2, 5, 4, -1, 0, 7 ,9];
$sum =0;

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if($val < 0) {
        break;
    }
    
    $sum += $val; // Вот тут накапливаем, а не выводим
}

echo $sum;
```

Надо накапливать значение, а за пределами сделать `echo`.

Comment: Вот Спасибо. Все ок. А то уже столько всего перечитал и попробовал(жаль не то что надо), а оно все просто оказалось.